# Converting base64 encoded pdf to file input stream without writing file to system

Tags: java, pdf, file-io, base64, pdfbox

I am getting a base64 PDF input as part of a request from my client, I need to convert this file into to File Input Stream to use with the PDF BOX library. I am trying to achieve this without writing the file onto drive and directly reading the base64 pdf into File Input Stream.

**What I am able to do:**
Convert base64 encoded pdf to File and write on the drive
Read the file into a File Input Stream

**What I want to do:**
Convert base64 encoded PDF to File input stream to use it with PDFBOX. 
I am trying to avoid writing the file onto the disk.

Comment: post some code.

Comment: A `FileInputStream` implies it comes from a file. Why not use another flaour of `InputStream`, like `ByteArrayInputStream` or `PipedInputStream`?

Comment: Load your PDF in a byte array and use `Base64.getDecoder().decode(...)` on it. Then write the resulting byte array to the output stream. What is your difficulty, specifically?

Comment: If you don't show the code of *what you are able to do*, it's hard to show how to adapt that code to do *what you want it to do*.

Answer (score 3):

In pdfbox you can load a pdf from an `InputStream`. it does not need to be `FileInputStream`.

Using the following code you can get an inputStream of the decoded pdf.
Note: depending on the scheme used to encode pdf you may need to use: `.getMimeDecoder()` instead of `.getDecoder()`.

```
InputStream decoded = java.util.Base64.getDecoder().wrap(inputStream);
PDDocument.load(decoded);
```